# pandas incorrectly parsing csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

I've created a CSV file from a dataframe with a shape of `(1081, 165233)`. I did this using this command: `df2.to_csv("better_matched.csv")`

However, whenever I try to load this csv as a pandas dataframe later on, the shape of the dataframe becomes `(660, 165234)`. This is the code that I'm using to load the csv:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Authorship/better_matched.csv")
df.shape
```

I think I need to change some parameters with `.to_csv()` or `.read_csv()` functions. What can be done?

Comment: Might be an issue with the headers and the delmiter

Comment: Can you double check that you are reading same file or directory?

Comment: I'm not sure why you lose so many rows when reading (or saving), but the 1 additional column is probably because you didn't specify `index=False` when saving, which means the index gets saved as a column and then read as a separate column.

Comment: Yes it should be about headers, delimeter or sth. I checked it is in the same directoru. I wil try to save index=False and notify if it works

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am trying but my system has difficulty in loading the data. By the way, making index=False would only get rid of the first column, I need to fix the missing rows problem actually.

Comment: Any ideas to help me? :)